# Can you auto generate HTML content with unique classes? *Edit* And how?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a button in my website that creates new firebase email and password user logins. 
Is there a way to add a

```
<tr>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><b>Number 0X</b></td>   
    <td>
        <div id="circleX" class="circle">&#8203;</div>                            
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn-0X mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Acknowledge
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

With X hopefully corresponding to the newly created login.
The `#circleX` class will then be used for a value event listener for entries under the newly created user and the `.btn-0X` will be used for an onclick event for writing data under the same newly created user. Will probably also need to initialize new variables that will correspond to database references to new users and data needed for read write.

Asking because the idea of having content automatically created but with their own class and/or id which will can serve different purposes seemed impossible to me. But with my limited experience with coding in general was not really sure.

Thanks.

*edit*

Was informed this was possible in comments, can someone provide me with how especially for the creating, using of new ids and variable?
Hopefully can start from there and implement it on my code.

Comment: The answer is: you can :)

Comment: Please use the class attribute for its intended purpose (**not** being a unique identifier for an `HTMLElement`). Use the `id` attribute (that **must** be unique by definition) as the unique identifier. And I echo @nicael's answer: _yes, you can_.

Comment: Oh... Thank you and will do, guess will now formulate question of how to do that. But knowing it is possible is a step forward, might be into more hardships but still.